# Problems while loading a function

Tags: function, arduino, switch-statement, arduino-ide, lcd

I have a problem when I try to load the "BrainTest" function in the "AppSelect" function.

I have created a method to notify me on the serial monitor and on the LCD screen when a loading error occurs.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// Arduino pins number
const int SW_pin = 2; // digital pin connected to switch output
const int X_pin = 0; // analog pin connected to X output
const int Y_pin = 1; // analog pin connected to Y output
const int LCD_RS = 7;
const int LCD_Enable = 8;
const int LCD_D4 = 9;
const int LCD_D5 = 10;
const int LCD_D6 = 11;
const int LCD_D7 = 12;
LiquidCrystal lcd(LCD_RS, LCD_Enable, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7);

// Basic vars
int none = 0;
String Apps[3] = {"App select","Credits","Test your brain"};
int CurrentApp = 0;
int Yaxis = 1;
int Xaxis = 1;
int HiCh = 0;
int button;
int JXaxis;
int JYaxis;


void AppSelect() {  //          APPSELECT
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("App select menu");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
  if (button == 0) {
    SelectApp();
  }
  if (JYaxis <= 2) {
    if (HiCh != 0) {
      HiCh = HiCh - 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
      delay(300);
    }
  }
  if (JYaxis >= 7) {
    if (HiCh != 1) {
      HiCh = HiCh + 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
      delay(300);
    }
  }
}

void Credits() {  //          CREDITS
  Serial.print("- Credits app loading \n");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(9,0);
  lcd.print("Credits");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Made by Alexandre Bergeron");
  Serial.print("- Credits app loaded \n");
  delay(1300);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(600);
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  delay(1500);
  CurrentApp = 0;
  lcd.clear();
}


void BrainTest() {  //          BRAINTEST
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Are you ready?");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Yes     No");
}


void setup() {  //          SETUP
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("[2J");
  Serial.print("  Serial Monitor opened \n \n");
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.print("- App selector menu \n");
  pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
}


void SelectApp() {  //          SELECTAPP
  switch (HiCh) {
    case (0):
      CurrentApp = 0;
      AppSelect();
    case (1):
      CurrentApp = 1;
      Credits();
      break;
    case (2):
      CurrentApp = 2;
      BrainTest();
    default:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Error");
      Serial.print("- App loading error \n");
  }
}


void loop() {  //          LOOP
  button = digitalRead(SW_pin);
  int JYaxis = analogRead(Y_pin) / 128;
  int JXaxis = analogRead(X_pin) / 128;
  if (CurrentApp == 0) { 
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(" App select menu");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
    if (button == 0) {
      SelectApp();
    }
    if (JYaxis >= 7) {
      if (HiCh != 0) {
        HiCh = HiCh - 1;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("App select menu");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
        delay(300);
      }
    }    
    if (JYaxis <= 2) {
      if (HiCh != 2) {
        HiCh = HiCh + 1;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("App select menu");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(Apps[HiCh]);
        delay(300);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need any other details, ask me and I will clarify it for you.

I don't know if my question name is correct so if you think I can improve it, you can tell me and I'll change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using `break` in the case, it'll fall through to the next one. That's basic design of C/C++ switch statement.

You can learn something more about C++ switch statement [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch).

Comment: Thanks! I think I did no just see the mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by your comment, but if you don't understand what's wrong, the `case (2):` do it's job and then it fall through straight into the `default:` part because there is no `break;`.

Comment: Sorry for my English I’ve understood the mistake